# PayPal AppID for Mobile Payment Library

Tags: ios, paypal

I am using PayPal MPL in iOS because I need chained and parallel payments (split the fee between the seller and me). It seems that I can't find where the PayPal AppID's are located to complete this in the app delegate:

```
[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX];
//[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"your live app id" forEnvironment:ENV_LIVE];
//[PayPal initializeWithAppID:@"anything" forEnvironment:ENV_NONE];
```

I registered my App on the PayPal developer website and I am given for sandbox a ClientID and a Secret, which are two separate numbers and cannot replace APP-8... I suppose that these are for the iOS SDK, however the SDK currently does not support parallel and chained payments, so the only alternative I would have would be to use HTTP requests. Furthermore when I open up the PayPal dialogue in iOS in Sandbox mode and enter my email and password it says that they are not valid.

Comment: Hello Alessandro, Can you help me to implement this, I want to do the same you did?

Comment: @BADRI, unfortunately I don't have this code anymore. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412809/paypal-error-580001-http-request-from-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Adaptive Payments (aka "classic") applications you'll need to go to https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications.

The login should be the PayPal account for your actual merchant account.